# Flexbox container slightly taller than its contents

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with 4 columns/flex items, each containing an image of the same size/proportions with the max-width set to 100%. Columns have an overflow property set to hidden since I want to scale images on hover but don't want them to expand outside their column's "boundaries". However, the container's height is 382px while the image height is 379.5px leaving a subtle gap of 2.5px on the bottom when hovering image. Please refer to the modified screenshot below (red line marks the bottom edge of the container, second/lighter image is in hover state) as well as the code.

I've tried setting the flex container's align-items property to center and I've tried removing whitespace in HTML, among other things, to no avail. I am trying to wrap my head around what might be causing this discrapency. From what I understand, the height of elements in CSS is determined by their children so I don't get why it's 382px in the first place if the height of each image is 379.5px.

Any help would be greatly apprecaited, thank you!

P.S. I'm using Eric Meyer's CSS reset.

[image: Red line marks the bottom edge of the flex container pronouncing the discrapancy of the container's height with the height of its children]

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="./img/img01.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="./img/img02.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="./img/img03.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="./img/img04.jpg" alt="Image">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    column-gap: 1em;
}

.flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-item > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-item:hover > img {
    transform: scale(1.125);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All what you need, just put to the `.flex-item` class `display: flex`.

```css
.flex-item {
  display: flex; /* new line */
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex; /* new line */
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-item > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.flex-item:hover > img {
  transform: scale(1.125);
}
```

```html
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### Expample 2

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.flex img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.125);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
  <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
  <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
  <img src="https://plchldr.co/i/400x400?&bg=ece2d0&fc=000" />
</div>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! Care to explain or point me in the direction of understanding why that works? Doesn't that effectively turn flex items into flex containers? I'm wrapping my head around the concept and can see it working even if they effectively were standalone containers due to each of them being a separate flex item of its parent container. I've worded this kinda fuzzy, hope you understand.

Comment: HTML has block and inline elements.The **div** tag is a block element. When *div* has `display: flex` it is became *flexible*, but for a child element. In your case you have two *divs* as a main container and for each image. Main *div* has *flexability*, but for image container not. I have added another snippet without image containers, to understand this better.

Comment: And you can read more about block and inline elements [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)